# What's this UI controller called?

Tags: user-interface, user-controls

The whole thing labeled by the red rectangle.

What's its name so I can search for it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZQVX.jpg

What I can think of is "List". But when I used "list Controller" it didn't math what I'm looking for.

Note: I want to know the common name of the controller it self, like: button, grid view, etc..

Comment: You might want to tag this with the platform that the control is meant for.

Answer (score 0):

A simple search with the terms in the image that's embedded in your question shows this is a [Telerik UI for WinForms](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/overview.html).

Hopefully, this was what you were asking for! I also strongly recommend following Matt's advice in order to get faster - and likely much more detailed - answers or comments.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the name of program, I want to know the name of the controller it self that's labeled by the red rectangle.

Comment: Ah, then that's an UI control. Or rather a list of UI controls. I don't think there is a specific name for this, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the highlighted with a red border control is RadListControl for Winforms. You can find its documentation at http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dropdown-and-listcontrol-listcontrol-overview.html

Check these two articles to learn how to customize the ListControl appearance:

http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dropdown-and-listcontrol-listcontrol-customizing-items-%28visual-appearance%29.html

http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/tpf-primitives-imageshape.html

This generic video shows how to create a custom theme for Telerik WinForms controls: http://tv.telerik.com/watch/winforms/episode-1-creating-custom-skin-for-radscheduler-with-visual-style-builder-for-winforms

If you have any questions, you can always post your questions in the Telerik Winforms forums or in the support ticketing system.